# Python boolean value reset itself

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, boolean

I've got a small python script thats starts a movie and I can pause the movie by pressing a button. But I cannot play the movie again by pressing the same button.
I run it on a raspberry, so I listen to the GPIO pin.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from omxplayer.player import OMXPlayer
from time import sleep

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(True)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

movie1 ='/home/pi/Downloads/big_buck_bunny_480p_surround-fix.avi'
status = None

def getButtonPress():
    while 1:
        if GPIO.input(18) == False:
            return True
            break

def statusMovie(status):
    print('Status')
    print(status)
    print('after if:')
    if status == True:
        status = not status
        print(status)
        return status
    else:
        status = not status
        print(status)
        return status

def main():
    print('begin main')
    print(status)
    try:
        player = OMXPlayer(movie1)
        while True:
            if getButtonPress() == True:
                if statusMovie(status) == True:
                    player.pause()
                    print('Stopping')
                    print(status)
                    print('end.....')
                else:
                    player.play()
                    print('restarting movie')
                    print(status)
                    print('end.....')
            sleep(2)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Closing Player')
        GPIO.cleanup()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if status is None:
        status = False
        main()
```

Well the movies starts playing, and I can pause the movie by pressing the button.
The problem is by my status boolean. I assign it at the start of running the script to False, Not sure if this is the right place to do it. Then I check and change it in the `statesMovie(status)` function.
I also change the boolean there so when I press the button again it can not only pause the movie.. But also play the movie again.
I dont know how but then the `stateMovie(status)` function return the value it change the value always to False back in the main function.

I got an output of the print's from the script:

- begin main
- False
- Status
- False
- after if:
- True <<<< Well here the boolean is correct!
- Stopping
- False <<<< But why is it False again!?
- end.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will just talk about what you ask:

The problem is that you are modifying a local variable but won't reflect to outside variable.

You pass `status` to `statusMovie` and want to toggle it from `True` to `False` or from `False` to `True`. But actually, you just toggle the local `status` but not the outside `status`. if you want to toggle the outside `status`, you need to update it explicitly by `status = statusMovie(status)`

Comment: To expand on this, you should do some more research on the scope of variables, and how to make changes to variables based on the context that you are using them in.